# Authorization header not present on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, identityserver4, kestrel-http-server

I have an C# solution consisting of:

- IdentityServer 4 application
- .net core 2.2 Web API
- React SPA

I login via the React app using Identity Servers Resource Owner Password flow. This works and I get an Access Token back.

I then call a method on the web api passing the access token:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public async Task<VMFranchiseGeoJson> GetByAuthorizedUser()
{
   try
      {
       var token = Context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
       var user = (Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
...
```

On the first call after logging in this works fine and token contains the Bearer token and Context.User.Identity contains the claims. However if I reload/refresh the page making this call, it works for the first or even a few times (doesn't seem to be after a set interval and is quite quick to lose the headers 2-3 minutes) and then stops working i.e. the authorization header is no longer there.

But...

It is being passed in the call to the API e.g. 'authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjAzMDg5OTk1YmJkNWVlY2...'

I am using CORS here as it's local development but I have it configured as:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Do you have to persist them in some way?

Tried multiple solutions, changing CORS policies, rewriting the Identity Server portion, changing flows etc

Edit for auth config @Alpha:

```
 services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine().AddAuthorization();

        //services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        //    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        //    {
        //        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        //        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        //        options.ApiName = "api";
        //    });

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = "api";
            });
```

Comment: Check the developer tools in the frontend, especially the network tab, it should show all the requests, see if you can find the failing request.

Comment: Thanks Ferrybig, the request isn't failing on the frontend. It gets sent including the authorization header which is not present on the backend.

Comment: How do you know it's not present in the backend? `GetByAuthorizedUser` won't hit if that's the case. Seems more likely the token expires after a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks Ruard, I have a breakpoint there which it hits. Noting that goes past the [Authorize] attribute which is also odd.

Comment: Could you show your authentication configuration in the Startup.ConfigureServices method?

Comment: Apologies added. I have tried both methods

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced yesterday, so the solution is, to put the headers setting logic in one main component like "Header" or "Footer" component which is always render with every page.

```
useEffect(() => {
axiosInstance.defaults.headers[
  "Authorization"
] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(`access_token`)}`;
```

}, []);

so when the header or footer component render in our application, automatically headers set their value "Authorization" and your API call will be call successfully.

Comment: This is very dangerous practice, never store sensitive token in localStorage otherwise the app will be vulnerable against XSS attacks.